# CancellationTokenSource vs manually ending Task

Tags: task, cancellationtokensource

Say I create a task

```
bool aBoolean = true;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    while(aBooloean)    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Is it better to exit the task by having a global boolean to exit the Task?

Or ist it better to use CancellationTokenSource?

When is it appropriate to use a CancellationTokenSource to end a Task?

Does it just throw an exception when you use CancellationTokenSource  and leave things in a inconsistent state?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a "global" boolean runs the risk of being optimized or cached into CPU cache and you may not see a change in value.  `CancellationTokenSource` is the *recommended* method for cancelling a `Task`.  The Task uses the Token to test if cancellation is requested and simply returns from the Task's Action delegate.  No need to throw an exception if you don't want to.

Comment: I did not know that, so if I set the Global boolean will it eventually pick up the change? Or will the change be only delayed because its in a cache?

Comment: It depends on several circumstances; sometimes never.  You can use a boolean field like this, as long as you declare it `volatile` or use `Thread.VolatileWrite` and `Thread.VolatileRead`.  One of the benefits of `CancelationTokenSource` is that it is decoupled from a particular implementation.  So, you could share a token amongst multiple tasks that you haven't written or any other code that supports a cancellation token.  which is very useful if you are doing tasks in parallel across multiple classes.